Android emulator вылетает, но процесс в диспетчере задач висит
После обновления Android Studio до версии Ladybug | 2024.2.1, Android emulator начал вылетать и при этом процесс завершить через диспетчер задач не получается.
Ошибок ни каких не выдает.
В Android Studio отображается что эмулятор работает.
Если долго не выключать ноутбук, то потом он зависает.
На прошлой версии Android Studio. Android emulator  работал без проблем.
Что пробовал и не помогло :

переустановка Android Studio
перезагрузка / выключение(на этом этапе просто зависает) 
Что бы хотя бы перезагрузить было можно без зависания, пробовал :
taskkill(не удается закрыть процесс)
программа Process Explorer( Отказано в доступе)

PS: В гугле  находит только что слабый ноутбук\ПК.
Вот характеристики моего:

Процессор:AMD Ryzen 5 6600H
Оперативная память: 16 ГБ DDR5
Видеокарта: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti


Эмулятор это самостоятельный инструмент, вы всегда можете его скачать, обновить, откатить независимо от AS. https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive

Это решило проблему на половину. Когда ноутбук на зарядке то все работает без проблем, но если ноутбук не на зарядке, то эта ситуация повторяется. Как можно выяснить из-за чего так?
